# Determining which font variants are actually used in a web page?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

Is there an easy way to find out which font variants are actually used within a page?

I'm working on a site that has a full font family imported, but would like to remove unused variations. I can go around inspecting elements, but figure there might be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools like Fount: https://fount.artequalswork.com/

But it's not time-consuming at all to do it by hand, really. If you're using Chrome just right click the page, go down to Inspect in the menu, and under the Elements tab you'll find the HTML of the page. Click inside the box and hit command + F to bring up the search box, and type in "css" so you can easily find their CSS sheets. Right click on the link and hit Open and you can search for the font from there (command + F again).